# Check if CSV file is empty or not after reading with DictReader

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm opening a CSV file and I need to check if the file empty or not, I already know about checking using getsize(). I would like a way by using DictReader.
This is my code

```
infocsv = open('nyfile.csv', 'a')
reader = csv.DictReader(infocsv)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
with open(parafile, "rb") as paracsv:         
    #Read in parameter values as a dictionary
    paradict = csv.DictReader(paracsv)
    has_rows = False
    for line in paradict:
        has_rows = True

    if not has_rows:
        return None
```

The number of lines read from the source iterator. This is not the same as the number of records returned, as records can span multiple lines.

Comment: I get this error at the for statement "self._fieldnames = next(self.reader) io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
import csv
with open('nyfile.csv') as infocsv:
    reader = [i for i in csv.DictReader(infocsv)]
    if len(reader)>0:
        print ('not empty')
    else:
        print ('empty')
```

I tried it on a few CSV files of my own and it works. Let me know if this helps.